# How do I show a button only on my custom template page?

Tags: css, headers

```
<button name="button" style="margin: 20px 0 0 796px;padding: 3px 25px; background-color: red;color: white;font-weight: bold;" value="OK" type="button"  >HAVE A QUESTIONS</button>
```

i make a button in my custom template page(header.php) but its display also my home page but i want to display only my custom template page.......how do i hide this button in my home page(front page)

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as doing a conditional and check if you are on home.

What you are looking for is `is_page_template( );`. Wrap your button inside it as follows:

```
<?php if( is_page_template( 'your-template-slug.php' ) ){ ?>
    <button name="button" style=" ... " value="OK" type="button">HAVE A QUESTIONS</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this in your css file

```
.home button[type=button] {display:none}
```

Comment: This will hide every other button on the page. Besides, it only hides it on homepage, which OP wants to only show it on his custom page.

Comment: OP says (s)he makes a button (not multiple buttons, so your argument that it will hide all buttons on the homepage doesn't make sense. The OP's question is: how do I hide this button in my homepage. The css I gave above does that exactly. It will hide the button.